# WPF Datagrid: How to change border thickness of a single cell programatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Im new to WPF

Im trying to change the border of a single cell depending on the column and row index.
So far I already have the code for getting the column and row index.

Now I need to get 'that cell' and change its border..

This is my Code , but its not working:

I got this method from net:

```
    public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);
        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
        {
            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = v as T;
            if (child == null)
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
            else
                break;
        }    return child;
    }
```

Then this where I need to change the cell properties..

```
           int rows = 0;
            int col = 0;
        while (col < myDG.Columns.Count)
        {
            rows = 0;
            while (rows < myDG.Items.Count)
            {
                DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)myDG.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rows);

                if (row != null)
                {

                    DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
                    DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(col);

                    cell.BorderThickness = new Thickness (2,2,2,2);
                    cell.BorderBrush= Brushes.Black;


                rows++;
            }
            col++;
        }
```

Any Idea? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid code behind in your WPF application. Prefer to set the thickness property to a binding property on your datacontext.

then you can convert this value to a valid value for that property by setting a valueconverter.

Here's a very basic example:
http://wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html

So if you're new to WPF try searching some video's about MVVM.
Laurent Bignon has made a few excellent ones to explain the whole concept

Comment: Im not familiar with XAML coding so as much as possible Im trying to do it in c# , but thanks for your response . Ill try it later.

Comment: if you don't want to dig into xaml you better stick to winforms. The advantage of WPF that you can use the databingings and decouple your form from all your code. This way you can improve the testability of your code. I know WPF has a big learning curve if you want to implement it properly but afterwards you will gain the benefits

Comment: Agree with @Jeroen, not only is MVVM cleaner it is also simpler than anything else I've ever seen. In the end you only have simple, simple properties and `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your ViewModels, and `{Binding}`s in your Views.